# Prove that $\|f\|_{q} \leq 1$ is closed for $f\in L^{p} \cap L^{q}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1 \leq p,q < \infty$.Prove that the following set is closed in . $\mu(X) < \infty$.

$$A = \{ f \in L^p \cap L^q : |f|^q \leq 1 \}$$

My attempt:

Let $f_{n}$ be a sequence of functions in $A$ such that $f_{n} \to f$ in $L^{p}$. It is enough to show that $f\in A$. $L^{p}$ convergence implies that there is a subsequence $f_{nk}$ converging almost everywhere to $f$. Then, since $f_{nk} \in L^{p}$ and it is convergent, and $L^{p}$ is complete, then $f \in L^{p}$. Then we apply Fatou's lemma to $|f_{nk}|^{q}$ as follows,

$$ \int \liminf |f_{nk}|^{q} \leq \liminf \int f_{nk}^{q} $$
$$ \int |f|^{q} \leq \liminf \int |f_{nk}|^{q} = 1$$

Thus, $||f||_{q} \leq 1$. Thus, $f \in A$.

Please let me know if the proof is correct? I have not used the fact that the measure space is finite.

Comment: Proof is fine. finiteness is not necessary. Fatou is the way to go.